# if there are two textviews on horizontal layout. second textview's text should continue below first textview's text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_overviewtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Overview:  "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:lines="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_overview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Underworld: Blood Wars follows 
        Vampire death dealer, Selene, as she fends 
        off brutal attacks from both the Lycan clan
         and the Vampire faction that betrayed her. 
         With her only allies,David and his father 
         Thomas, she must stop the eternal war between
         Lycans and Vampires, even if it means she has to
         make the ultimate sacrifice."
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_overviewtitle"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have two TextViews as shown :

[image: textviews]

In the next line, I want `"Selene, as she fends....."` to start from beginning of the line. From below "O" of Overview. What do I do?

Comment: consider adding the full layout for a better comprehension

Comment: ya I'm trying but it is not coming.

Comment: btw you removed my fix on the code, this is not correctly formatted.. set it back with the code tag instead of quote one

Comment: This is my first post and entire code is not coming here.

Answer (score 0):

Well your text, if I understood it correctly, will be somethind like

```
Overview   MyFirstText written
           on more rows but
           always alligned
           like this
MySecondText which is written 
this way, so aligned like the
Overview text and fullscreen
```

So, you have a couple of ways. the first Which comes in my mind is the following:

```
<!-- this layout will contain the full text -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >
  
<!-- this layout will contain overview and the first text -->
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_overviewtitle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Overview:  "
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:lines="1"/>
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_overview"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Underworld: Blood Wars follows Vampire death  dealer, scelene, as she fends off brutal attacks from both the Lycan clan and the Vampire faction that betrayed her. With her only allies, David and his father Thomas, she must stop the eternal war between Lycans and Vampires, even if it means she has to make the ultimate sacrifice."
         />
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_secondText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Selene, as she fends....."
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

I wrote it without any compiler, so if it has any problem please tell me and I will fix

hope this helps

## **I understood it now, my bad I missunderstood previouvsly**

so, simply do a different thing:

on Java side, istantiate your `textView`.

```
TextView myFullText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_overview);
```

now, **use a single textview for all the text**

set in your String.xml file the full text like this:

```
<b>Overview:</b> Blood Wars follows Vampire death  dealer, scelene, as she fends off brutal attacks from both the Lycan clan and the Vampire faction that betrayed her. With her only allies, David and his father Thomas, she must stop the eternal war between Lycans and Vampires, even if it means she has to make the ultimate sacrifice.
```

As you can see I added the `<b>` sign which is the `bold` in html.

now set the text with:

```
myFullText.setText(Html.fromHtml(/*here retrieve the string from the String.xml*/));
```

This will work

Comment: @RadhikaParmar look second part

Comment: @RadhikaParmar I said in the second part to take the text from string.xml, but u can take it from everywhere

Comment: Sorry if I have accidentally deleted something. I have few inbox messages which say that. I was trying to fix.  @Pier

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single textview and formatting the text with html tag, like this:

```
TextView myTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Lorem</b> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus tellus, gravida bibendum mi vitae, bibendum..."));
```